# show the html div id and rearrange the rest

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have 5 divs , with different id's. I want to make a step formation like if i get the value(from url) measures
example:

, it shows me the first div with id measures and rearrange the rest of the divs including fabrics which exists before measures div and so on

Then after, when i click the  Next button it shows me the rearranged div one by one.

I have done this whole code using php and jquery.

Is it possible to do this using jquery or javascript or anything, Please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

my Code is

```js
var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
 allWells = $('.setup-content'),
 allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
 allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn');


 allWells.hide();

 navListItems.click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
 $item = $(this);

 if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
 navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-success');

 $item.addClass('btn-primary');

 allWells.hide();
 $target.show();
 $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
 }
 });

 allPrevBtn.click(function(){
 var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
 curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
 prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");

 prevStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
 });

 allNextBtn.click(function(){
 var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
 curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
 nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
 curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
 isValid = permission;



 $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
 for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
 if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
 isValid = false;
 $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
 }
 }

 if (isValid)
 nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
 });

 $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">  // i will change it's id to fabrics
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-xs fabric_button" id="fabric"> Next </button>
 </div>
 <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2" > // i will change it's id to patterns
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-xs" type="button" id="pattern" >Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3" > // i will change it's id to measures
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-xs" type="button" id="pattern" >Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row setup-content" id="step-4" > // i will change it's id to Pair
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-xs" type="button" id="pattern" >Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="row setup-content" id="step-5" > // i will change it's id to total
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-xs" type="button" id="pattern" >Next</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: where is your jQuery code? Also what issue you are facing? Please clarify?

Comment: Ok let me change my code to original one

Comment: Here i've pasted the code(Jquery and html)

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I'm sorry for that.

I have step wise div i.e. step-1,step-2,step-3,step-4,step-5
My code shows the div starting from step-1
But I want to display the div according to the value i'm getting from url, like I am getting step-4 from url, It must show me the div with id step-4 first and when i click on the next button it should take me to the left over div i.e step-1 then step-2 then step-3 and last the step-5.